Lenovo Legion WMI query shows the location of the battery as fake. Does this mean the battery is fake?
I recently ran a query using WMI on my Lenovo Legion Windows 11 Computer and I noticed this:

The location of the battery says fake. Does this mean the battery is fake?

No, it means the Location field is fake.
The other fields indicate that the system firmware doesn't provide information about the actual battery through DMI/SMBIOS data, so the whole WMI object is made up.

+1 Thank you sorry about the delay in accepting the answer!
